# React Jquery Data Table No data available in table

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables

I am new to react. For my purpose i used jquery data table for my project.It's worked very well. but the problem is it's showing the first row as "No data available in table", after then only showing my data. How to solve this problem. If any one can help it will be much appreciable.

My code is just like below. In which the data is coming from load() method.

```
$.DataTable = require("datatables.net");
class Forward_To_Ho extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getList = this.getList.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      forwardtoholist: [],
      selected: [],
      forwardToHoError: "",
      selectedaccountid: 0
    };
    this.loadList();

    // this.loadList = this.loadList.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    ForwardToHoStore.on("changefho", this.getList);
  }

  //WARNING! To be deprecated in React v17. Use componentDidMount instead.
  componentDidMount() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#forwardtohotable").DataTable();
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // You might need to use eval(result)
    ForwardToHoStore.on("changefho", this.getList);
  }

  loadList() {
    ForwardToHoAction.getAllForwardToHo();
    //  this.setState({
    //    forwardtoholist: ForwardToHoAction.getList()
  }
```

Foolwed by my table with id "forwardtohotable".

Comment: Could you create a demo? Add some data (two rows will be enough). Or, at least, screenshot to see the problem (is the `No data available` persist or is it hides when data is loaded?)

Comment: `getList` returns data loaded with `loadList`? Are you appending the `no data available` row with some logic in `getList` or is it done by the plugin?